# Serialize multiple objects in the same file

Tags: java, serialization, multiple-instances

I'm writting a program that has few objects (let's call them Books), and each one has an arrayList inside (array of pages).
Later on: I want to serialize some objects from different arrayLists.
But it seems that if I want to write to the same file it overwrites my previous recrods...

Is there any way to make method WriteObject(obj) add new record, not overwrite previous one?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

- Write a list of books instead and each time you need to add a new one, add it to the list and write it again ( or read it, add it  and write it if the list is not in memory already )
- Or write to a different file.

In other words, either you want to serialize a "bookshelf" object, or treat your directory as a bookshelf adding new books ( in different files )

In your existing situation is like trying to save a book in the same space used by other.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless I was hopping for something different